# If $\sup_{T\in \tau}|y^*(Tx)|<\infty$ then $\tau$ is bounded in $L(X,Y)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space, $Y$ a normed vector space and $\tau\subset L(X,Y)$.

Show that if $\sup_{T\in \tau}|y^*(Tx)|<\infty$ for all $x\in X,y^*\in Y^*$

then $\tau$ is bounded in $L(X,Y)$.

Seems that we have to use the Banach-Steinhaus theorem which would yield that $\tau\subset L(X,Y)$ is bounded.

But I don't know how to show that $\tau$ is points wise bounded. I don't see any connection to the assumption.

Comment: Alright, thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

First let us fix $x\in X$. Now we consider the family of functionals $Y^*\to\mathbb{C}$
given by
$$\tau' = \{ y^*\mapsto y^*(Tx)\,:\,T\in\tau\}.$$
By assumption we have
$$\sup_{T'\in\tau'} |T' y^*|=\sup_{T\in\tau} |y^*(Tx)|<\infty$$
Also note that $Y^*$ is complete. Thus we can apply Banach-Steinhaus to $\tau'$ and get
$$\sup_{T'\in\tau'} \|T'\| = \sup_{T\in\tau}  \sup_{\|y^*\|_{Y^*}=1} |y^*(Tx)| < \infty$$

**Claim:** Let $B$ be a Banach space. Then for all $b\in B$ we have
$$\|b\|_B = \sup_{\|b^*\|_{B^*}=1} |b^*(b)|$$

*Proof:* The canonical embedding map $\mathrm{ev}:B\to B^{**}$, $b\mapsto (b^* \mapsto b^*(b))$ is injective and (most importantly for us) norm preserving (follows from Hahn-Banach, you can look it up in any introductory text book). Thus
$$\|b\|_B=\|\mathrm{ev}(b)\|_{B^{**}}=\sup_{\|b^*\|_{B^*}=1} |b^*(b)|.$$
$\square$

By the claim it follows that

$$\sup_{T\in\tau}  \|Tx\|_Y < \infty$$

for all $x\in X$. Thus we can apply Banach-Steinhaus to see that $\tau$ is bounded.

Comment: Since I am new to this I hope you can help me step by step: Why are we applying Banach Steinhaus to $y^*(Tx)$? I also don't know why the equality holds:But I know that $\sup_{||y^*||_{Y^*=1}}|y^*(Tx)|\leq \sup_{||y^*||_{Y^*=1}}||y^*||\cdot||Tx||_Y=||Tx||_Y$

Comment: No problem, I added the details.